Templates not found when using flask
My problem is when i run return render_template("templates/home.html") it returns the error that could not find a template here it is
File "C:\Users\gamal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1010, in get_template
return self._load_template(name, globals)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gamal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 969, in _load_template
template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gamal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py", line 125, in load
source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gamal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 65, in get_source
return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\gamal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 99, in _get_source_fast
raise TemplateNotFound(template)

thats just all the error thing happing.
i really dont know what to do i try to use google but found nothing
(btw i am using pycharm)

I suppose your code should be:
return render_template("home.html")

"templates" directory is default.
If it's not the case, please show your project structure.
